# SQL -how to remove all ASCII char (blanks after field entry)

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, ascii

I have spent way to much time trying to figure this out.... looking a dozens of other answers.

I have table in SQL Server with a column of type `Char(32) NULL`. All items in the table column are only `char(9)`, but I have blanks in the remaining spots (when running `select ascII(right(myField, 1))` there is a 32 in there).

I have tried a replace, tried to update the field from a tempTable tried to delete and update from tempTbl..... everytime I select... the fields are still 30 in length.

Is there a way to remove all of the extra spaces?  or is this just the way the `CHAR` fields always work?

I have tried:

```
UPDATE table  
SET myfield = rtrim(replace(myField , char(160), char(32)))

UPDATE mytable
SET myField  = REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(myField )), CHAR(32), '')
```

Comment: The values will always be 32 characters because your datatype is CHAR(32). This will right pad the value with spaces until it hits 32. If you don't want the spaces padded you should consider using varchar(32) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must distinguish between

- strings with **fixed width** and
- strings with **variable width**.

In your case you are dealing with a fixed width. That means, that the string is always padded to its defined length. *Fixed-width-strings* live together with datetime or int values *within* the row.

If you define your column as `VARCHAR(32)` (meaning *variable characters*), the "32" is just limiting the max length. These values are stored (in most cases) somewhere *outside of the row's storage space*, while there's *only a pointer* to the actual storage place *within* the row.

Fixed lenghts are slightly faster then variable strings. But in most cases I'd advise to prefer the `VARCHAR(x)`.

Check this out:

```
DECLARE @fix CHAR(32)='test';
DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(32)='test';

SELECT LEN(@fix),DATALENGTH(@fix)
      ,LEN(@variable),DATALENGTH(@variable)
```

Which results in

```
4,32,4,4
```

- The **`LEN()`-function does not count the trailing spaces**
- The **`DATALENGTH()`-function gives you the space actually used**.

Comment: Great explanation.... ok...yeah, so I guess we are going to have to change to varchar in order to get what we really need.  thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

char(32) will occupy all 32 characters.

If you want it to be trimmed and stored, you should use varchar(32).

Try converting your field to varchar.